# Setting up wamp server for Perl

Tags: perl, wamp

I am following the steps given in the following 2 links to setup wamp server for perl
https://shravanthimohan.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/configuring-perl-on-wamp/
http://chromicdesign.com/2009/05/setting-up-perl-for-wampp.html

However I am not able to run the perl scripts, the error says that the requested URL can not be found

I am also not able to run the command 'ppm repo add uwinnipeg'
I am getting the following error, NOT NULL constraint failed: repo.packlist_uri

Please help me out

Comment: Maybe a look at the ActiveState perl documentation will help... as a last resort of course [ActiveState Using ppm](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.14/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html)